# Angular Reactive Form and hiding Elements

Tags: angular

I have a page in my Angular App which displays a grid, also in some cases there might be a filterbar on the left of the grid. The data for the filter comes from a db. We pass the grid id to the filterbar code which then retrieves all items and builds the filter list. All that works fine except when a grid has no filters, it still shows the bar but its empty.

Below currently is my template code for the filterSidebar which handles if its collapsed or not

```
<!-- SideBar-->
    <div class="{{filtersSidebarContainer.isSidebarCollapsed ? '' : 'col-md-2 pr-md-0'}}">
```

this is the code for my grid portion of the page

```
<!-- GRID -->
    <div class="{{filtersSidebarContainer.isSidebarCollapsed ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-10 pl-md-0'}}" *ngIf="isGridLoaded">
```

what i am trying to do is to check first if filterConfigId is null, if so go dont show the Sidebar and make the Grid col-md-12, Since there is no bar we dont need to handle colapse. If the filterConfigId is not null we go and display normal. Whats the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, i would only suggest to add the ngIf on the sidebar and using ngClass on it instead.

if false, ngIf will not render the sidebar at all, so you gain a little bit of performance

```
<!-- SideBar-->
<div *ngIf="filterConfigId" [ngClass]="{'col-md-2 pr-md-0': !filtersSidebarContainer.isSidebarCollapsed}"


<!-- GRID -->
<div *ngIf="isGridLoaded" class="{{filtersSidebarContainer.isSidebarCollapsed ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-10 pl-md-0'}}" >
```

I did not change anything for the grid because it's already fine like this...
If you would have added a condition for filterConfigId on it, you would have lost in performance since isSidebarCollapsed already does the job.

**EDIT**

```
<!-- GRID -->
<div *ngIf="isGridLoaded" class="{{!filterConfigId || filtersSidebarContainer.isSidebarCollapsed ? 'col-md-12' : 'col-md-10 pl-md-0'}}" >
```

Comment: Thanks that approach gets me half way home. But the problem is that if there is no SidebarContainer it fails the grid since it cant determine if the SidebarContainer does not exist. Cannot read property 'isSidebarCollapsed' of undefined

Comment: @NoSoup4you Ok, I understand now, I edited my answer according to your comment, let me know if it works for you :)